# A FormData object is always empty when trying to upload a file using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

When trying to upload an image using AJAX without submitting the form directly and sending a FormData object to server it returns empty `$_FILES` array. But if I submit the form using `<input type="submit">` tag `$_FILES` array is not empty and recieves the data.

**HTML**

```
<form action="core/update.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="profile-photo" name="profile-photo-form">
  <input type="file" id="photo-filename" name="avatar" class="edit-show panel photo-upload">
</form>
<button class="save-button" disabled="disabled">Save</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#profile-photo').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#profile-photo')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    formData.append('avatar', $('#photo-filename')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: "core/update.php", 
      data: formData,
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: false,       
      cache: false,             
      processData: false
    });

    console.log(formData);
});

$('.save-button').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#photo-filename').val != '') {
        $('#profile-photo').submit();
    };
}
```

**UPD**

Also `$('#profile-photo').serialize()` returns blank string.

**UPD 2**

Can it conflict with the other AJAX-requests on the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Why are you adding the file input twice? It is already in the form that you add using `new FormData(form)`.

Comment: Just in case. I tried a lot of variants of adding data but FormData is empty.

Comment: Check the network tab and see if the data is being sent to the server.

Comment: Musa, the request is being sent. 
Request payload:
`------WebKitFormBoundarykKBm9n5RL1SEIQD5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="s369unD7-50[2].jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarykKBm9n5RL1SEIQD5--`

Comment: Do you have any server side redirects?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Because user may upload multiple files

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('#photo-filename')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
```

Instead of

```
formData.append('avatar', $('#photo-filename')[0].files[0]);
```

Complete Solution:

```
$('#profile-photo').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

var form = $('#profile-photo')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);

 jQuery.each(jQuery('#photo-filename')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('file-'+i, file);
});

$.ajax({
  url: "core/update.php", 
  data: formData,
  type: "POST", 
  contentType: false,       
  cache: false,             
  processData: false
});

    console.log(formData);
});
```

Comment: I guess there is nothing wrong in your code you might be checking contents on `update.php` by `$_POST` you must use `$_FIELS`

Comment: No, I'm checking `$_FILES` array and it returns Array()

Comment: Is this written on your update.php
`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_FILES);
}`

Comment: change it to `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: This is what I have mentioned in my first comment

Comment: `$_FILES` array is also blank.

Comment: Every thing is working fine at my end. You must check other part of your code

Comment: This is obviously NOT the right answer. It is his right to only append the first file!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
$('#profile-photo').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this); // here I am editing

    formData.append('avatar', $('#photo-filename')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: "core/update.php", 
      data: formData,
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: false,       
      cache: false,             
      processData: false
    });

    console.log(formData);
});
```

Comment: It didn't worked :( Also, the FormData obj looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8gnrby1egwtveo/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA.JPG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If it is only the file you want to send then you can do it as below and no need to attach form here to `formdata`:

```
$('#profile-photo').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var fileInput = $('#photo-filename');


    //Use Either this
    $.each($(fileInput).get(0).files, function (index, value) {
           formdata.append('avatar', value);
    });

    //Or this
    $.each($(fileInput).get(0).files, function (index, value) {
        formdata.append(value.name, value);
    });

    //For single file use this
    formData.append('avatar', $('#photo-filename')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: "core/update.php", 
      data: formData,
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: false,       
      cache: false,             
      processData: false
    });

    console.log(formData);
});
```

Comment: Still nothing. Neither the first solution nor the second.

Comment: Can you just show how you are `submiting` the `form`??

Comment: Clicking on `<button class="save-button"></button>` object fires a function `if ($('#photo-filename').val != '') {
   $('#profile-photo').submit();
 };`

Comment: Can you edit the question and insert it in question? the whole process??